# Scrapy: Can't create object of a class having *arg and **kwarg in init

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, scrapy

In my scrapy spider I need to create object of another spider.

```
class SpiderA(SomeSpider):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(SpiderA, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
```

I need to create object of SpiderA in SpiderB

```
class SpiderB():
    def __init(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(SpiderB, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        spider_a_obj = SpiderA().__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
```

I tried creating spider obj using SpiderA().**init**(*arg, **kwargs) but it gives error,

```
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I shall be grateful for any help. Thanks

Comment: ```spider_a_obj = SpiderA(*args, **kwargs)``` worked!

Answer (score 0):

`spider_a_obj = SpiderA(*args, **kwargs)`
worked!